# Salvar alterações de um app carregado no shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em `Shiny` que vou upar no [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/).

Ele consiste numa tabela já carregada que o usuário pode selecionar alguma linha, e então é gerado um relatório baseado na linha selecionada.

Além disso, o usuário pode alterar alguns dados da linha selecionada e então é gerado um relatório atualizado. Porém, o dado alterado só permanece enquanto a linha está selecionada.

O que eu quero é que ao alterar algum dado, o usuário possa apertar um botão para salvar essa alteração. Assim, quando ele ou outro usuário entrar no link do app os dados alterados já estejam atualizados com as alterações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma possível é que a cada clique no botão `salvar` você salve todos os seus dados em algum lugar. Esse lugar pode ser no S3 da amazon, algum banco de dados, etc. Mas não pode ser o disco local. Eu recomendo usar o Dropbox.

O [rdrop2](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2) tem uma interface bem legal.

O melhor lugar para achar um exemplo funcionando é [aqui](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html).

Um exemplo simples, que é o que está lá é o seguinte app:

```
library(shiny)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "used_shiny", "r_num_years")

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    textInput("name", "Name", ""),
    checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
    sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R", 0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })

    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })

    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })     
  }
)
```

Com as funções `loadData` e `saveData` definidas da seguinte forma:

```
library(rdrop2)
outputDir <- "responses"

saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- t(data)
  # Create a unique file name
  fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv", as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
  # Write the data to a temporary file locally
  filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), fileName)
  write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
  # Upload the file to Dropbox
  drop_upload(filePath, dest = outputDir)
}

loadData <- function() {
  # Read all the files into a list
  filesInfo <- drop_dir(outputDir)
  filePaths <- filesInfo$path
  data <- lapply(filePaths, drop_read_csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
  data <- do.call(rbind, data)
  data
}
```

Veja que você precisará fazer o setup do rdrop2, que está bem explicado na página do pacote.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, já fiz uns testes com o shinyapps.io e tá dando tudo certo! Fiz o esquema  de criar um token com     token<-drop_auth() e to carregando nas funções drop_, mas não sei como essa autenticação funciona. Tem como eu restringir o acesso ao app a conta do dropbox que o app foi criado? Ou liberar acesso a algumas contas do dropbox?